# Pages now showing after pushing to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've succesfully submitted my app to git, and then pushed it to heroku. Starting page working as it has to, but the rest with path heroku_site.com/pages/page_name says me "We're sorry, but something went wrong." Same pages works fine on local server. 
Any ideas whats wrong?

inb4 routes are fine(and rest too, rspec spec/ green)

Comment: and what's your production log is showing ?

Comment: actually was doing the lesson from book http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top chapter 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view your Heroku logs with `$ heroku logs`

Looking at your routs, I'd guess that your page is based on content in your local database that you have not added yet to your production database.

If so, you can either push your local database to production `$ heroku db:push`

Or you can put that data in a Rails migration or seed it. Or you can go create it in your production app.

In general, to find out what you can do: `$ heroku help`